# How can I retrofit pom.xml to an IntelliJ project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have created a project in IntelliJ, and it's working. Now I want to use Maven. OK so I add pom.xml, no problem. When I add a dependency, the class files get that red circle with a lone through that tells me the files are now outside of the project:

[image]

I know that I can go to *File > Project Structure > Modules* to fix this:

[image]

BUT! when I go back and edit my pom file, the red circles of death come back.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to re-make the project?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when using Maven project IDEA will follow Maven guidelines for the source and test roots location, for example Java sources must be located in `src/main/java`, not just in `src` like on your screenshot. So either follow Maven rules or don't use Maven.

Comment: Thanks, yes now I realise! Cheers, Andy

Answer (score 2):

The `src` directory shouldn't be a source directory--you should follow the [Maven directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) or be prepared for a world of hurt. For example, Java source files should live in `src/main/java`.

You should remove the default IntelliJ `out` directory and make sure you're compiling to `target`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm still learning, but what you say mnakes sense. Cheers, Andy

Answer (score -1):

I am not experienced with IntelliJ, but you do know that Maven stores dependency jars it downloads in a directory separate from your project right? For instance, on Windows 7 it stores the jars in C:\Users\YourUserName.m2\repository . Hope that helps.